# Using php code in html to list images

Tags: php, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this code :

---

```
   <?php    
            // Grab the data from our people table
            $sql = "select * from people";
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error());

            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
            {
            echo "<br><br><br><br>";
                echo $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'] . "<br />";
                echo "<img class=\"picture2\" src=\"images/" . $row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />";

                echo "</p>";
            }?>
```

---

to list some images that have been saved by name in the database ... but when I want to put them in a table (using bootstrap components), it doesn't show any images ... my code is :

---

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
    <?
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
    echo $row['fname'] . " " . $row['lname'] . "<br />";
    echo  "<img class=\"img-rounded\" src=\"images/" .$row['filename'] . "\" alt=\"\" />          <br />";

echo "</p>";
    }?>
    </div>
    </div>
```

---

Do you have any clue what i've to do to list images in the table ?
and my second question is how can I list images in just two columns ? it's not important how many rows does it take to show images but i want it to show two images in a line (but in two separated cells) ...

Comment: Any idea where approximately the fail starts? Does the query have an error? Does it have results? Does it print anything? Is the printed HTML valid? etc

Comment: If you are having a hard time with the quote escaping an stuff, you could use single quotation out of double quotation e.g. `'<img class="img-rounded" src="images/' .$row['filename'] . '" alt="" />'` or open and close php tags like: `?><img class="img-rounded" src="images/<?=$row['filename']?>alt="" /><?` (just for the tip)

Comment: I see that you end each image with a closing paragraph tag.. Yet I do not see any opening tag.  What happens if you remove it?

Comment: @Daedalus removed it ... nothing changed .

Comment: @rudie the fail is that there isn't any image in the table, even there isn't any image there . when I use <div class="row"> <div class="col-md-6"> etc, it doesn't work but with the first code I can list images ....

Comment: I take back my previous request.  Where does the first block of code take place, and where does the second take place?  Since the path is relative, I wonder if its a problem of the image source.

Comment: Also, is this on your local machine, or is there an actual url where we can debug this from another standpoint?

Comment: @user3078441 Does all HTML print correctly? Check the source. Give it to us. Also open the browser's devtools: any errors a la "Can't load me this image" or "This HTML ain't valid yo"?

Comment: there isn't two block of code, the second part of code is where it fails, but first block works correctly . main code is mix of first and second block ... i mean declaring database connection and after that     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"> ...

Comment: So you tested both of these snippets on the same page then?

Comment: @Daedalus it's on my local machine, working with mamp ... my problem is it list fname and lname correctly but there isn't any image yet ...

Comment: I know what your problem is, what I don't know is the information that I asked for; its relevant, and you haven't provided it.  Help us help you.

Comment: Show Error Console got me this : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Comment: The first things that come to mind in that regard are your .htaccess file and your file permissions.

Comment: http://oi42.tinypic.com/33joinb.jpg

Comment: http://oi40.tinypic.com/317b88z.jpg

Comment: @Daedalus it works !!! the img tag wasn't closed ... but now my problem is how to list images in 2 columns ?